# Calculating and plotting differences in kernel density distributions in r

Tags: r, distribution, difference, kernel-density

I'm using R and I want to calculate the differences between two Kernel density distributions at each point on the x axis and plot that difference but am having some trouble. Is there a certain function or way that I can do this? For context, I'm using blood pressure data and I want to calculate the differences at each point in the blood pressures between men and women.

My code for the distributions (not the differences) looks something like this (SBP=systolic blood pressure):

```
km <- density(data$SBP[data$GENDER==0], bw="nrd0", adjust = 1, kernel = c("gaussian"), window = kernel, n=512, cut=3, give.Rkern = FALSE, na.rm=FALSE)
kf <- density(data$SBP[data$GENDER==1], bw="nrd0", adjust = 1, kernel = c("gaussian"), window = kernel, n=512, cut=3, give.Rkern = FALSE, na.rm=FALSE)

plot(km, xlab="SBP", main="SBP Distribution of Men & Women", col="blue")
lines(kf, col="green")
```

I am completely new to all this! I'm pretty sure my exact question has also not been asked here but please lead me to any other resources that may help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `density` objects have elements `x` and `y` elements that store the x-axis and distribution function values repectively. If you use the same `from` and `to` arguements for both `density()` calls, then the `x` values calculated should be the same.

Store the x-y values for both densities in a dataframe an d then merge/join them on `x`, then you can calculate the difference and plot them:

```r
x <- rnorm(1000,0,1)
y <- rnorm(1000,1,1)
fx <- density(x,from = -5,to=5)
fy <- density(y,from = -5,to=5)
plot(fx,col='blue',main="SBP Distribution of Men & Women")
lines(fy, col="green")

dfx <- data.frame(x=fx$x,
                  fx=fx$y)

dfy <- data.frame(x=fy$x,
                  fy=fy$y)

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)
```

[image]

```r
inner_join(dfx,dfy,on='x') %>% 
  mutate(diff=fx-fy) %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(x=x,y=diff))
#> Joining, by = "x"
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This works!!! Thank you so much! How do i add an x and y label to the difference plot?

Comment: Try [this](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labs.html). For more info, see http://r4ds.had.co.nz/